# How to terminate a thread subprocess call and thread exit in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am trying to run subprocess Popen in a thread in Python. The command in Popen is expected to run continuously to collect logs. But when a condition is met outside the thread, I want to stop the Popen subprocess and the corresponding thread also to finish. Below is a sample representative code:

```
import threading
import subprocess

class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
    
    def run(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen("while true; do foo; sleep 2; done", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = self.proc.communicate()
            
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.start()

myclass.proc.kill()



print("Done")
```

But in the above code, it gets stuck forever. What is the correct way to stop the running Popen subprocess and also to finish the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do is to have the thread, i.e. the `MyClass` instance, do the "killing" and instantiate `MyClass` with an event that it will wait on and then when set will kill the process. As I do not know what is in `foo`, I have substituted a simple `echo hello` for that and have set *text=True* on the `Popen` call so that the output is Unicode rather than bytes:

```py
import threading
import subprocess
import time

class MyClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, evt):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.evt = evt

    def run(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen("while true; do echo hello; sleep 2; done", shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        # wait for the "kill" order:
        self.evt.wait()
        proc.kill()
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        # for demo purposes let's see what has been output:
        print(stdout, end='')

evt = threading.Event()
myclass = MyClass(evt)
myclass.start()

# let the process run for 5 seconds and then give the kill order:
time.sleep(5)
print("Killing process:")
evt.set()
myclass.join()
print("Done")
```

Prints:

```
Killing process:
hello
hello
hello
Done
```

Answer (score 1):

Add param  `preexec_fn=os.setsid` to your `Popen` func.

Use `os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGKILL)` to kill sub process by pid.